# Calling lambda with non-parameter template argument

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

MSVC 2019 allow me to define a lambda like this, where the template argument is not used in the parameter list:

```
auto foo = []<bool B>() {
  return B;
};
```

However, it gives syntax error when trying to call it like this?

```
foo<false>();
```

What is the correct way to call a lambda with a non-parameter template argument?

Comment: `foo.operator()<false>();`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The template parameter is used with `operator()` of [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

> (since C++20) If the lambda definition uses an explicit template parameter list, that template parameter list is used with operator().

You can specify the non-type template argument for `operator()`, call the lambda in an unnormal style as:

```
foo.operator()<false>();
```

Answer (score 4):

`foo` is a function object.  It has an `operator()`.  The template on a lambda is on that operator, not on the object name itself.

`foo<T>` attempts to give the name `foo` a template argument `T`; that isn't valid here.  `foo<T>()` gives the template argument to `foo`, then calls `()` on the result.  Again, not what is going on here.

A template variable would work the way you want this to:

```
template<bool B>
auto foo = []() {
  return B;
};
```

such variables only work in global scope, but here `foo<true>()` would work.

As a lambda is actually a compiler-generate class:

```
struct some_secret_name {
  template<bool B>
  auto operator()() const {
    return B;
  }
};
some_secret_name foo;
```

then the "right" way to call it is the ugly syntax:

```
foo.operator()<true>();
```

this, honestly, sucks.

You can get slightly better syntax like this:

```
template<class T> struct tag_t {using type=T;};
template<class T> constexpr tag_t<T> tag_v={};
template<auto v> using value_t = std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(v)>, v>;
template<auto v> constexpr value_t<v> value_v={};
```

then we can do

```
auto foo = []<bool B>(value_t<B>) {
  return []{
    return B;
  };
};
```

now the syntax is:

```
foo(value_v<false>)();
```

which looks a bit less cludgy, if overly magical.

`foo` is now a lambda that makes lambdas, the outer lambda takes your template parameters as function arguments, and the inner lambda is the body.